# Merge pattern line/s with line before

Tags: regex, sed, awk

I need to print all lines merging the lines starting with a white space "^ " with the line/s before. Using awk or sed would be perfect.

From:

```
ext_bus     3  0/1/1/0/1/1    c8xx           CLAIMED
                             /dev/c8xx3
target      4  0/1/1/0/1/1.0  tgt            CLAIMED
disk        4  0/1/1  sdisk          CLAIMED
                             /dev/c3t0   /dev/c2t0
                             /dev/c4t0
```

To:

```
ext_bus     3  0/1/1/0/1/1    c8xx           CLAIMED /dev/c8xx3                          
target      4  0/1/1/0/1/1.0  tgt            CLAIMED
disk        4  0/1/1  sdisk          CLAIMED /dev/c3t0   /dev/c2t0 /dev/c4t0
```

Comment: I tried sed -n '/^[a-z]/{x;p};/^[^a-z]/{H;x;s/\n\s*\([^a-z]\)/ \1/;x};${x;p}', but it gave me "cannot parse", and I thought it wouldn´t do any good to post it :)

Comment: It's **always** better to tell us what you have tried !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) (more portable than [Suhas's `sed` answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15548941/465183) in your case):

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/\n\s+/ /gms'
```

`-0777` read the whole file in a string

The [substitution modifiers](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers) are mandatory there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sed -e :a -e '$!N;s/\n\s/ /;ta' -e 'P;D' <filename>
```

Comment: In Linux your solution works. But unfortunately I´m working in Unix (HPUX), and it doesn´t work. Any idea to do the same in Unix?

Comment: Try this?
`sed ':a; $!N;s/\n\s/ /;ta;P;D' <filename>`

Comment: sed: The label :a; $!N;s/\n\s/ /;ta;P;D is greater than eight characters.

Comment: Okay, honestly, I have no clue about sed and HPUX. Ideally the GNU sed should behave similar across platforms?

Comment: I think the problem is that sed in HPUX is not GNU sed. I found that commands should be given in different lines. Tried but didn´t work. Perl answer worked perfect in HPUX. Thank you anyway (your answer was perfect for GNU sed).

Answer (score 0):

sed is an excellent tool for simple substitutions on a single line. For anything else, just use awk:

```
$ awk '{printf "%s%s", (gsub(/^[[:space:]]+/,"")?" ":nl), $0; nl="\n"} END{print ""}' file
ext_bus     3  0/1/1/0/1/1    c8xx           CLAIMED /dev/c8xx3
target      4  0/1/1/0/1/1.0  tgt            CLAIMED
disk        4  0/1/1  sdisk          CLAIMED /dev/c3t0   /dev/c2t0 /dev/c4t0
```

The above handles each input line one at a time and doesn't read the whole file into memory but if that's acceptable then here's the GNU awk (for `RS='\0'` to read the whole file as a string) equivalent of @sputnik's perl script if anyone cares:

```
$ gawk -v RS='\0' -v ORS= '{gsub(/\n\s+/," ")}1' file
ext_bus     3  0/1/1/0/1/1    c8xx           CLAIMED /dev/c8xx3
target      4  0/1/1/0/1/1.0  tgt            CLAIMED
disk        4  0/1/1  sdisk          CLAIMED /dev/c3t0   /dev/c2t0 /dev/c4t0
```

In non-gawk awks, just set RS to some control char that doesn't appear in your input file.